# How to optimize periodic Bluetooth scanning in a .NET MAUI app to prevent lag?

Tags: android, .net, bluetooth-lowenergy, maui, android-bluetooth

I am developing a .NET MAUI app for Android that continuously scans for Bluetooth Classic and BLE devices using platform-specific code. The app collects data from the scanning process and stores it in a local SQLite database. However, after running for a few hours (1 - 2), the app starts to lag. Also, I have noticed that when the app is not scanning during the periodic pause periods, it remains fully responsive. Interestingly, when I stop the scanning, the lag disappears.

To address this issue, I switched from continuous scanning to a periodic scanning pattern, where the app scans for a specific duration and then pauses before the next scan cycle. This should have helped improve the app's responsiveness and prevent any lag issues.

I suspect that the continuous and periodic scanning process is overwhelming the mobile device. What are some best practices and optimizations I should consider to prevent this lag issue? I want to ensure that the app can run continuously without performance degradation.

Here are some details about my implementation:

- I'm using platform-specific code for Bluetooth scanning in Android.
- Data is stored in a SQLite local database.
- I'm scanning for both Bluetooth Classic and BLE devices.
- The lag issue becomes noticeable after a few hours of continuous scanning.

I'm open to any insights or recommendations that can help improve the app's performance and stability during continuous Bluetooth scanning.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using background services in the platform specific implementations?
e.g `AndroidService` for Android?
If not, you might have code running on the UI thread that would be causing this issue.
You can use `WeakReferenceMessenger` to communicate from a background Service to the UI thread if needed.

Comment: I am utilizing a foreground service to perform Bluetooth scanning even when the app is closed. Additionally, I employ a Handler to execute tasks in the background with a delayed post. The issue at hand does not pertain to the background service, executing code in the main thread, or updating the UI. My question is centered around whether anyone has successfully implemented this and, if so, how they managed to maintain continuous operation without encountering any performance issues or interruptions.